# Macbook air built in trackpad not detected

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have an macbook air early 2015. When I go to trackpad settings it only tries to detect bluetooth trackpad. My built in trackpad works fine but is not detected in preferences. My macbook runs on power and no batteries are there. It has both mojave and high sierra installed. Same problem in both OS.

Somewhere in this forum it is discussed few years back that without battery macbook fails to detect built in track pad. Is there any solution found now?

Comment: This seems like a hardware problem that needs a hardware solution. - the most obvious of which is to put a battery in.